Data Tables in Excel - How to think about it?
Has anyone come across an explanation of how a one-dimensional and two-dimensional Data Table "works"? A conceptual model, something like: "the table takes the values ​​from this place to this place that are here, puts them in a variable here, gets the result there, pushes the result to such and such a cell"?
The model I have in mind works fine for a one-dimensional table but not for two-dimensional ones.

See e.g. https://spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-use-data-table-in-excel/
In a one-dimensional table, you can have one independent variable and multiple formulas that refer to that variable. In a two-dimensional table, you have one formula and two independent variables, one in a column and one in a row.
